# Jquery mobile: how to close a pop up dialog page from code?

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

I am opening a pop-up dialog like-

```
<a href="routeEdit.php" data-role="button"  data-icon="gear" data-inline="true" data-theme="b" data-transition="pop" data-rel="dialog">Edit</a>
```

Now, from that page, calling a method submit().

How will i close the pop-up from submit() method- without redirecting to main page?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$('#myDialog').dialog('close');
```

Try above coding. It's working for me.

Answer (score 8):

If you use pop in jQ Mobile 1.3.0,then

```
 $("#popupLogin").popup('close');
```

wourld be used.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$(".ui-popup").popup( "close" );
```